# Marlene Dietrich Deutsches Lied

Tags: lyrics, listening-comprehension

I understand some German and am just testing listening skills. I found this song by Marlene Dietrich and have a hard time understanding, could somebody help write the Liedtext in German?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCbDJ9K9UxU

Comment: This is the poem _Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt_ bei Heinrich Heine. The youtube video's title says it was a lullaby, which it is not. Just fyi, the melody is by Felix Mendelssohn, I believe.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I was able to find the songs you are a big help

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: I don't quite understand the rationale behind posting a (great!) answer as a comment.

Comment: The question asked for the lyrics. I didn't have time to type them out. I was also distracted by thinking about closing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt
Liebliches Geläute.
Klinge, kleines Frülingslied,
Kling hinaus ins Weite.

Ein Männlein steht im Walde ganz still und stumm;
es hat von lauter Purpur ein Mäntlein um.
Sagt, wer mag das Männlein sein,
das da steht im Wald allein mit dem purpurroten Mäntelein?

Answer (score 1):

Marlene Dietrich sings the first verse of Heinrich Heine's poem [Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt](https://www.gedichte7.de/leise-zieht-durch-mein-gemuet.html):

> Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt
> liebliches Geläute,
> Klinge, kleines Frühlingslied
> Kling hinaus ins Weite.

Then she sings the first verse of  August Heinrich Hoffmann von Fallersleben's children's song [Ein Männlein steht im Walde](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_M%C3%A4nnlein_steht_im_Walde):

> Ein Männlein steht im Walde
> Ganz still und stumm,
> Es hat von lauter Purpur
> Ein Mäntlein um.
> Sagt, wer mag das Männlein sein,
> Das da steht im Wald’ allein
> Mit dem purpurrothen Mäntelein?

She finishes with both verses of Heine's poem:

> Leise zieht durch mein Gemüt
> liebliches Geläute,
> Klinge, kleines Frühlingslied
> Kling hinaus ins Weite.

> Kling hinaus, bis an das Haus,
> wo die Blumen sprießen.
> Wenn du eine Rose schaust,
> sag, ich lass sie grüßen.